# Yodlee: Force 90 days of transactions

Tags: yodlee

I've seen in the docs that Yodlee can fetch up to 90 days of transactions. I added a Chase account, and using executeUserSearchRequest I specified a time range of the past year, but it only pulled in the first 25 transactions.

This is obviously because Chase only shows 25 transactions per page.

How can I get Yodlee to retrieve 90 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteUserSearchRequest should return all the transactions if it is available in Yodlee DataBase, while if you are not receiving all transactions for mentioned duration which should be returned in response. I would request you to raise a Service Request using Yodlee Customer Care tool else you can contact [here](http://solutions.yodlee.com/APIDeveloperInquiryForm.html) raising your issue with other details.